# BASH : Array as String Buffer

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-script

Instead of displaying (or writing) every result once generated, i designed an *Array* based *Buffer* to store data and write it whenever the line counter reaches a MAX value. Here is the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#Buffer Management
BUFFERCURSOR=0
BUFFERMAXSIZE=5
function bufferReset (){
    unset BUFFERVAR
    BUFFERCURSOR=0
}
function bufferAppend () {
    (( BUFFERCURSOR++ ))
    BUFFERVAR[$BUFFERCURSOR]="$1"
}
function bufferDisplay () {
    for ((i=1;i<=$BUFFERCURSOR;i++)); do printf "%s\n" "${BUFFERVAR[$i]}" ; done
}
#Buffer Management End:
for ((i=1;i<=8;i++)) ; do
    line=`printf "%3s" "$i ==> $(echo $i | md5sum|awk '{print $1}')"` #Example of a string to append
    bufferAppend "$line"
    if [ "$BUFFERCURSOR" == "$BUFFERMAXSIZE" ] ;    then
        bufferDisplay
        bufferReset
    fi
done
# Display remaining elements in the "buffer"
bufferDisplay
bufferReset
```

So the output is :

```
1 ==> b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
2 ==> 26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510
3 ==> 6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03
4 ==> 48a24b70a0b376535542b996af517398
5 ==> 1dcca23355272056f04fe8bf20edfce0
7 ==> 84bc3da1b3e33a18e8d5e1bdd7a18d7a
8 ==> c30f7472766d25af1dc80b3ffc9a58c7
```

Why the 6th element is skipped ?

Comment: Replacing the _bufferDisplay_ function code by `printf "%s\n" "${BUFFERVAR[@]}"` solves the problem. But still dont know why !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem can easily be seen by starting the script as

```
bash -vx ./script
```

You use the same variable in the main program and in a function which is a really bad idea. `bufferDisplay` leaves i at value 6 after which the `i++` of the main loop is executed.

The best way to avoid this is to use a separate name space in all functions. Every variable in a function which is not intentionally the one from the outer name space must be declared like

```
local i
```

You could use different names, too; especially with such a small propgram. But the `local` approach is less error-prone.

Comment: +1 vote for the `-vx` bash option :) !